# Construct a target string from a list of substrings

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm doing a little side project where I'll need to arrange existing substrings that will output a target string. I'm having trouble with a particular case, though. Let's say I want to form the sentence:

"The brown fox is cool."

And I'm given the inputs

["The brown fox", "The", "brown", "is cool"]

If I am implementing this naively, I would go word by word and start forming "The" + "Brown" only to realize that I would have actually had to begin with "The Brown Fox." It could also be the case that it's not possible to create the target string.

This sounds a bit like dynamic programming, but I'm having trouble formalizing it and handling the two cases I mention above. Would anyone mind giving me some help, or point me to somewhere I can read up on a similar problem?

Comment: Can we use the same word twice from the list to build the target string?

Comment: @YashShah Yes, you can use the same word twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Let's take examples to understand better:

**Example-1:**

*Input:*

target = "The brown fox is cool."

arr    = ["The brown fox", "The", "brown", "is cool"]

*Output:*

True

**Example-2:**

*Input:*

target = "The brown fox is cool."

arr    = ["The brown", "The", "brown", "is cool"]

*Output:*

False

**Example-3:**

*Input:*

target = "The brown fox is cool."

arr    = ["The brown fox is", "The", "brown fox", "is cool"]

*Output:*

True

*Explanation:*

Even if you always choose the largest matching substring, You are not going to achieve the correct answer.

**Recursive Approach:**

**Step-1:** Use your current index to match with the strings of the list i.e. arr.

**Step-2:** For each element of the arr, First you have to match the target string from the index.

**Step-3:** If that matches, you need to find if it is possible to match the remaining target string by increasing its index.

**Step-4:** Thus at the end of the recursion, you will get to know if it is possible(true) or not(False) based on their return value.

**Python Code:**

```
def match_string(string, target, index):
    lens = len(string)
    lent = len(target)
    
    if(index + lens > lent):
        return False
    
    for i in range(index,index+lens):
        if(string[i-index] != target[i]):
            return False
    
    if(target[index+lens] == " " or target[index+lens] == "."):
        return True
    else:
        return False

    
def solve(arr,target,index):
    
    n = len(arr)
    ln = len(target)
    
    if(index == ln):
        return True
    elif(index > ln):
        return False
    
    result = False
    for em in arr:
        if(match_string(em,target,index)):
            result = result or solve(arr,target,index+len(em)+1)
    return result
   

target = "The brown fox is cool."
arr    = ["The brown", "The", "brown","fox", "is cool"]
answer = solve(arr,target,0)
```

**Dynamic Programming Approach:**

Just use the index to remember the result of each recursive step.

```
def match_string(string, target, index):
    lens = len(string)
    lent = len(target)
    
    if(index + lens > lent):
        return False
    
    for i in range(index,index+lens):
        if(string[i-index] != target[i]):
            return False
    
    if(target[index+lens] == " " or target[index+lens] == "."):
        return True
    else:
        return False

    
def solve(arr,target,index,dp):
    
    n = len(arr)
    ln = len(target)
    
    if(index == ln):
        return True
    elif(index > ln):
        return False
    
    if(dp[index] != None):
        return dp[index]
    
    result = False
    for em in arr:
        if(match_string(em,target,index)):
            result = result or solve(arr,target,index+len(em)+1,dp)
    dp[index] = result
    return dp[index]
    

target = "The brown fox is cool."
arr    = ["The brown fox", "The", "brown", "is cool"]
dp = [None for i in range(len(target))]
answer = solve(arr,target,0,dp)
print(answer)
```